# Adding clickable button to Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I want to add a button to top right corner (20px from top and 20px from right) of my Leaflet map. Problem is I am not sure how to do this properly. The problem is when I use that leaflet class "leaflet-top leaflet-right", my button is not clickable, and when I hover over it, nothing happens. It just remains as a part of the map.

Here is my html code:

```
        <div id="mainContainer">
            <div id="mapDiv">
                <div id="map">
                    <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right">
                        <div id="refreshButton"><div id="refreshButtonPictogram"><img src="pictograms/refresh.png" height="30px"></div></div>
                    </div>>
                </div>  
            </div>          
            <div id="bars"></div>
        </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
#mainContainer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    display: flex;
}

#bars{
    z-index: 0;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(214, 49, 65);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#mapDiv {
    flex: 1;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

#refreshButton{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-align: center;
}
#refreshButton:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#refreshButtonPictogram{
    margin: auto;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
  #mainContainer {
    flex-direction: column; 
  }
  #mapDiv,
  #bars {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have u set z-index property well? If ur button is not clickable i think u should try manipulate z-index

Comment: yes I tried even setting the z-index of #refreshButton to 10000 and it did not work

Comment: And what with other z-index? Have u tried to remove and set only this one z which u need? I’ll check tommorow your code, I can’t now

Comment: yeah basically I tried everything with z-index, as far as I know. I am new to webcoding though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following worked for me:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <button id="refreshButton">Refresh Button</button>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#refreshButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 400;
}
```

And here is [a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/daluves/3/edit?html,css,output) with the above code.

[image: Refresh button on top of map]

Screenshot taken from the JSBin linked above.

I also came across [this resource on creating a custom control button in leaflet](https://web.archive.org/web/20191218192541/http://www.coffeegnome.net/control-button-leaflet/).

### Update

I changed your HTML to the following:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="mapDiv">
    <div id="map">
      <button id="refreshButton">
        Button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bars"></div>
</div>
```

I also changed the `#refreshButton` position rule to `absolute` and gave it a z-index of 500.

In addition to that I added

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Take a look at the updated solution in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gepolet/2/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Yeah I tried the position absolute, but as you can see in my code, it is structured like there is map on the left, and bars on the right. When I use position absolute resizing browser's window breaks that. Or I am not sure how to do this properly - button remains on the same position even when window is resized.

Comment: oh I have it. I had to set "position:relative" to the ancestor div. Silly me

Comment: Okay, good job figuring it out! I also just updated my answer to use the HTML you specified in your question.

Comment: Which ancestor div did you end up giving a position of `relative` to?

Comment: mapDiv. And I removed that leaflet class.

Comment: When I click the button in your JSbin, it has no button effect. However, because you did not stop event propogation, it zooms the map

Comment: The button just prints some text to the console when clicked. If you open the Console tab on JSBin and click the button on the map, you'll see the log statement get printed.